# Stretch Static TableViewCells

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

To access my database information, I thought it would be best to create static cells for an information page, tie the labels where information will be inputted to a property, and then display that information on my custom static cell. So something like this:

```
Name: NameLabel
Date: DateLabel
Time: TimeLabel
```

`Name` and `NameLabel` are two separate labels in my custom static `TableViewCell`. `NameLabel` is attached to the property `*nameLabel` in my .h file and in my .m file I have:

`self.nameLabel.text = @"Test TEST Test TEST Test TEST Test TEST Test TEST";`

to display some test data.

The problem that I'm having is that I cannot stretch the Static TableView cells vertically to fit the text. I know how to do a `heightForRowAtIndexPath` but this will not work for static cells, as it requires a custom cell identifier, etc. Is there a way to do this? Is there a better way to achieve this goal?

Comment: There is one Property of UILabel numberOfLines,make self.nameLabel.numberOfLines = 0.It will work.

Comment: I have this set (as well as good constraints) but it's not enough to stretch the static cell.